# Xenomai resources

Tags: linux, xenomai

I have just started to familiarize myself with Linux, and I was wondering if you guys could help me find good resources (easy enough to understand) with instructions on running Xenomai with Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about [this](http://www.cs.ru.nl/lab/xenomai/) one? It's up-to-date course material for a course called *Design of Embedded Systems (DES)* by a Dutch University and I found it always helpful to get started (e.g. by following the [exercises](http://www.cs.ru.nl/lab/xenomai/exercises/index.html)). ;)